# Word for something that stands out

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that this might seem like an obvious answer to some of you, but when I research "word for something that stands out," I get synonyms for "stand out." I do not need a synonym for the verb "stand out"; **I need a noun for *something that stands out.*** Here is my sentence:

> Those are just three things that stood out to me.

This is a formal paper, so including what I have above in my paper is not going to work. Any help is appreciated. **:)**

NOTE: I am not looking for "sore thumb"; the term "sore thumb" is more appropriate for a negative context, and what I am referring to within my paper is not negative whatsoever.

Comment: [A sore thumb.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/to-stick-out-like-a-sore-thumb)

Comment: @HotLicks A "sore thumb" seems more appropriate for a negative context. There is nothing negative about what I am referring to, but I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong or informal about *that stood out*. Google Scholar has 34,000 instances of "that stood out".

Comment: @PhilSweet Do you think this is the only option? Should I continue trying to find a noun for something that stands out, or should I stick with "things that stood out"?

Comment: There's no harm in letting the question stand, but you should provide more context - like a paragraph. The noun *standouts* exists, but Google Scholar has only 10,000 of those, and almost all of them refer to people. And it has a different connotation than something that was noteworthy.

Comment: I think your main problem is the use of first person in the paper.

Comment: There are phrases such as "points of interest" but I'm not sure there's a single word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Those are just three things that stood out to me**.

In regard to the answer above, if you alter your sentence then you could use a noun. For example.

*There were just three things that* **drew my attention**

or

*There were just three things that* **immediately drew my attention**

**attention**
noun [ U ]
UK  /əˈten.ʃən/ US  /əˈten.ʃən/
attention noun [U] NOTICE, thought, or interest:

Comment: This is basically what I was looking for. Thank you for your help, Brad! :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me *eminences* and *prominences* are the only nouns for things that stand out and are positive, but they'd both stick out like HotLicks's sore thumbs.
Perhaps we've never felt the need to name such things with a single word.

"Three things that stood out" is perfectly plain English. You could say they became clear or were apparent, or call them noticeable things or prominent *features*, or choose your adjective from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/synonyms/noticeable)'s *noticeable, perceptible, discernible, detectable, distinguishable, observable, perceivable, visible, easily seen, appreciable, recognizable, notable, distinct, evident, obvious, apparent, manifest, patent, plain, clear, clear-cut, marked, significant, conspicuous, unmistakable, undeniable, palpable, pronounced, decided, prominent, salient, striking and arresting*, but "three things that stood out" is fine in any context.

Comment: You make a good point, Old Brixtonian. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

> identified

as in

> These are the three features I identified with the most

From [TheFreeDictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/identified):

> to associate oneself with or admire something, such as a set of ideas

Comment: Yeah, I don't identify with what I am talking about. But I appreciate your help, JMP! :)

Answer (score 0):

*Those are just three **highlights**.*

> the best or most exciting, entertaining, or interesting part of something:
>
> *Highlights of the match will be shown after the news.*
>
> — https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/highlight?q=Highlights+

Answer (score 0):

Those are just three of the: **Attractions,  enticements, temptations, seducements**

**Attraction**: (4) something that attracts or is intended to attract people by appealing to their desires and  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attraction

**Temptation**: the act of tempting or the state of being tempted especially to evil https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temptation

**Enticement**: c. 1300, "thing which entices," from Old French enticement "incitement, instigation, suggestion," from enticier (see entice). From 1540s as "action of enticing." [www.etymonline.com/search?q=enticement&ref=searchbar_searchhint](http://www.etymonline.com/search?q=enticement&ref=searchbar_searchhint)

**seducement**: something that serves to seduce https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seducement